# Python saying variable mentioned before assignment when it is assigned in the for loop it's nested in?

Tags: python

**EDIT**
Well I'm an idiot for deleting the thing I'm looping through. Thanks y'all.

---

I've tried looking up answers but honestly this is just boggling me.
I have a for loop which loops through lists in a list, but then in an if statement nested into the for loop it says the thing it is looping with is not defined?

```
for monster in self.monsters:
    print("google chrome")
    if monster[1][1] <= 0:
        self.exp_gotten += monster[1][8] 
        for j in self.turns:
            if j[0] == monster[1][0]:
                del j
                self.defeated_monsters.append(monster)
                del monster
```

self.monsters is a list containing other lists for the monsters. The lists are like ["Monster Name", [monster_id, hp, mp, ...]]. Monster[1][1] is the HP stat, and it checks if it is smaller than 0, indicating its been defeated. It then adds the exp, then deletes the monster from the turns list, adds it to the list of defeated monsters, then deletes the monster itself.
 Except when it comes to this part, I keep getting "monster variable referenced before assignment"

```
File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Dave's stuff\Python\COURSEWORK\battle.py", line 150, in check_if_fin
    if j[0] == monster[1][0]:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'monster' referenced before assignment
```

I just don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Smells like the indentation broke.

Comment: uh, you *explicitly* delete the name: `del monster` ... what did you think that does? It isn't removing it from your list, it is merely deleting the name, but that will be in your list. Anyway, that's what causes your error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your inner `for` loop deletes the `monster` variable:

```
    for j in self.turns:
        if j[0] == monster[1][0]:
            del j
            self.defeated_monsters.append(monster)
            del monster
            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If `self.turns` contains more than one element and and anything but the last enters the `if` block, you'll delete `monster` and get that error. You probably want to throw in a `break` statement or otherwise exit the loop if you're done.

It's tricky to remove objects from a list that you're currently iterating over. One solution would be to use intermediate lists:

```
new_monsters = []

for monster in self.monsters:
    # It's usually clearer to remove unnecessarily nested `if` statements
    if monster[1][1] > 0:
        continue

    self.exp_gotten += monster[1][8] 

    for j in self.turns:
        if j[0] == monster[1][0]:
            self.defeated_monsters.append(monster)

            break  # Don't continue checking, you've already defeated the monster
    else:
        # We never broke out of the above loop, so we never defeated the monster
        new_monsters.append(monster)

self.monsters = new_monsters
```

Finally, code like `monster[1][8]` and `monster[1][1]` is really difficult to manage. Consider setting up your monster as a class with descriptive attributes or at the very least a `namedtuple`. That way, you can use `monster.exp` instead of `monster[1][8]`.

Comment: That is definitely a real bug in the code, but I would expect it to cause a `NameError` rather than an `UnboundLocalError`. If I'm not mistaken, the latter is a compilation error that would be raised before the code even runs.

Comment: Throwing in a `break` statement will mean the other `j`'s won't be deleted. Whatever these `j`'s are; the code is rather opaque as to what the variables represent. Rather, the OP should just just move the last two statements up one indent level.

Comment: @DavidZ `UnboundLocalError` can be raised at runtime.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, I see... it has to be in a function. OK, I didn't realize that. Never mind me then.